# Strange issue while tracking port events with BAM

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2, biztalk-bam

I have a very strange behavior while tracking data with BAM on BizTalk Server 2013 R2.

The same activity and Tracking profile work fine, but on some ports, no data is tracked, with no error (event log, BizTalk, failed tracked data (table TDDS_FailedTrackingData), no active tracking, no continuations).

The only difference between working ports and non working ports is the promoted properties. On the working ports, I have, the property BamTrackingOnly (http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/xmlnorm-properties) is in the context (not promoted), while it is not present on the non working ports.

Do you know this property ?

Moreover, the issue appears on BizTalk Server 2013 R2. I also notice that the type of messages are "Unparsed Interchange", or "Serialized Interchange".

How can I fix this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was finally a bug. A private patch could be got by calling Microsoft Support.